# Getting exception whenever promise gets rejected in the NodeJS application which causes app restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, axios, bluebird

I am looking into an error occurring in our production application. Which is NodeJS based application and there are REST API's written in it. We are facing a problem with one of the API say /data/.

So, whenever a request comes we fetch info for that data from 2 different sources. And return info from the source for which the request successfully resolved first. 
For this, we are using Bluebird promise library's "any()" method http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html

```
const GetdataPromise = (promises: Array<Promise<any>>) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    BluebirdPromise.any(promises)
      .then(response => resolve(response))
      .catch(BluebirdPromise.AggregateError, err => reject(err.shift()))
  );
};

export const GetdataData = async (p: string) => {
  const key = `p.${p}`;
    let responsePromises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];
    if (ShouldGetdataData(data)) {
        responsePromises.push(GetdataInfoFromN(p));     
        responsePromises.push(GetdataInfoFromP(p));
    }
}

await GetdataPromise(responsePromises)
        .then((response: any) => {
          logger.info(`final p response received ${p}`, JSON.stringify(response));
          data = response;
          shouldUpdatadataCache = response.success;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          logger.error(err, "error getting p response");
        });
    }
  }
  return !data.success && cachedData.success ? cachedData : data;
};

const GetdataInfoFromP = (p: string): Promise<any> => {
  let url = `${BASE_URL}/api/p=${p}`;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AxiosGet(url, { timeout: 15000 }, "p response", p)
      .then((response: any) => {
        if (response.data.status.result === "success") {
          responseData = ProcessPdataResponse(p, response.data);
          resolve(responseData);
        }
        reject(responseData);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        logger.error(err, `p err ${p}`);
        responseData["RESULT_MESSAGE"] = "Unable to getresponse.";
        reject(responseData);
      });
  });
};

export const GetdataInfoFromN = (p: string): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AxiosGet(url, { timeout: 10000, headers: { Authorization: `Basic ${AUTH}` } }, "p response n", p)
      .then((response: any) => {
        if (response.data.dataNumber === p) {
          logger.info(`nGet p info result for p no ${p} ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
          resolve(responseData);
        } else {
          responseData["RESULT_MESSAGE"] = response.data.errorMessage ? response.data.errorMessage.split("-")[0] : "Unable to get P response.";
          reject(responseData);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        responseData["RESULT_MESSAGE"] = "Unable to get p response.";
        logger.error(err, `error in nGet p ${p}`);
        reject(responseData);
      });
  });
}
```

The problem we are facing with this is that when the promise gets rejected the exception occurs and application gets restart. Though we are using catch to handle it.

There are few exceptions which are getting generated:-

```
 ERR [2019-10-04 13:33:47,525] [p data] data err p 4364081301 Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded
    TypeError: this._currentRequest[method] is not a function
        at RedirectableRequest.(anonymous function) (home/data/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:139:40)
        at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (home/data/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:216:13)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    TypeError: this._currentRequest[method] is not a function
        at RedirectableRequest.(anonymous function) (home/data/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:139:40)
        at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (home/data/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:216:13)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    ERR [2019-10-04 13:33:58,376] [p data] data err paT-mX90rto 2301753220 Error: timeout of 15000ms exceeded
    TypeError: this._currentRequest[method] is not a function
        at RedirectableRequest.(anonymous function) (home/data/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:139:40)
        at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (home/data/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:216:13)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    TypeError: this._currentRequest[method] is not a function
        at RedirectableRequest.(anonymous function) (home/data/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:139:40)
        at Timeout.handleRequestTimeout [as _onTimeout] (home/data/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:216:13)
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
    ERR [2019-10-04 13:34:13,567] [p data] data err pError: timeout of 15000ms exceeded
```

We are using PM2 as a process manager with two clusters for our app.
But these exceptions are causing PM2 process to restart.

```
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode    │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu  │ mem       │ user   │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ c        │ 2  │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 15057 │ online │ 31041   │ 18s    │ 5.2% │ 61.5 MB   │ ubuntu │ disabled │
│ c        │ 3  │ 1.0.0   │ cluster │ 15131 │ online │ 31003   │ 14s    │ 0%   │ 50.4 MB   │ ubuntu │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

We have tried returning promise(responseData) tried returning err object promise(err) from GetdataInfoFromP() and GetdataInfoFromN() but no luck.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you wrapping promise returning methods in a new promise? Explicitly wrapping the promise in another promise is similar to the [deferred anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns). Use `return` statements on the promise returning methods and do not mix `async/await` with traditional promise handling.

Comment: thanks @JakeHolzinger will refactor this part.